# tf2_ros buffer transform PointStamped?

Tags: ros, tf2-ros, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to transform a `PointStamped` using a python `tf2_ros.Buffer`, but so far I'm only getting type exceptions.
The following example a point with only a y component is supposed to be trivially transformed into the frame it is already in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import sys
import tf2_ros

from geometry_msgs.msg import PointStamped

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('transform_point_tf2')
    tf_buffer = tf2_ros.Buffer()
    tf_listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(tf_buffer)

    rospy.sleep(1.0)
    pt = PointStamped()
    pt.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    pt.header.frame_id = "map"
    pt.point.x = 0.0
    pt.point.y = 1.0
    pt.point.z = 0.0

    try:
        pt2 = tf_buffer.transform(pt, "map")
    except:  # tf2_ros.buffer_interface.TypeException as e:
        e = sys.exc_info()[0]
        rospy.logerr(e)
        sys.exit(1)

    rospy.loginfo(pt2)
```

This results in:

```
[ERROR] [/transform_point_tf2] [./transform_point_tf2.py]:[27] [<class 'tf2_ros.buffer_interface.TypeException'>]
```

If PointStamped isn't the right type, then what type can I use?

To do this manually I'm currently doing this:

```
            trans = self.tf_buffer.lookup_transform("map", target_frame,
                                                        rospy.Time())

            quat = [trans.transform.rotation.x,
                    trans.transform.rotation.y,
                    trans.transform.rotation.z,
                    trans.transform.rotation.w]
            mat = tf.transformations.quaternion_matrix(quat)
            pt_np = [pt.point.x,
                     pt.point.y,
                     pt.point.z,
                     1.0]
            pt_in_map_np = numpy.dot(mat, pt_np)

            pt_in_map.x = pt_in_map_np[0]
            pt_in_map.y = pt_in_map_np[1]
            pt_in_map.z = pt_in_map_np[2]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249433/tf2_ros-buffer-transform-pointstamped?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2016-12-05

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jsanch2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/25919/jsanch2s/) on 2016-12-05**:
Could you post the output of  `tf_buffer.registration.print_me()`?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-12-05**:
In this example it is `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code that registers transforms is in tf2_geometry_msgs. The following code will allow you to call the *BufferInterface.transform* function.

```
import tf2_ros
from tf2_geometry_msgs import PointStamped
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point

...

# Let src_pt be the point you want to transform.
tf_buf = tf2_ros.Buffer()
tf_listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(tf_buf)
target_pt = tf_buf.transform(src_pt, "target_frame")
```

Note that you should not include a leading slash in the name of the target frame.

---

Originally posted by [J. Bromley](https://answers.ros.org/users/29210/j.-bromley/) with karma: 66 on 2017-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Note:** This is not really an answer but it was too long for a comment, sorry.

As I understand it, `Buffer` inherits from [BufferInterface](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/blob/indigo-devel/tf2_ros/src/tf2_ros/buffer_interface.py), where it uses `TransformRegistration` (also defined in the same file) to check if a type is supported, in this case PointStamped. Specifically, it uses the method `get` to check if that type is supported. Since the output you posted is an empty dictionary, I'm assuming there are no supported types.

They also define an `add` method that requires the type and a callback (no idea where to get this callback, though).

Perhaps the authors of this package can provide an insight?

---

Originally posted by [jsanch2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/25919/jsanch2s/) with karma: 136 on 2016-12-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2